# How do I use regex to match the last word of an expression but not match an optional last word?

Tags: regex

Say I have this regex:

```
(?:begin\s+)?(\S+)(?:\s+\S+)*\s+(\S+)(?:\s+end)?
```

(optional begin, a word, an arbitrary set of words, a word, optional end, all separated by spaces)

And this expression:

begin test1 test2 test3 end

I want to use the parentheses to match "test1" and "test3" from this expression. Whether the word "begin" is in the expression or not, "test1" matches successfully because "begin" was made optional. However, "test3" is only matched if "end" isn't there (if "end" is there, "end" is matched), even though "end" was made optional in the same way. How do I change this so that I can ignore the word "end" if it's there?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: With only one example, it's unclear what you want to match when there are multiple begin and end, which might be inside each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
(?:begin\s+)?(\S+)(?:\s+\S+)*?\s+(\S+)(?:\s+end)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qB1dB8/2)

but pay attention to fact, that it use `/gm` modes